# string in function arguments in c++ explaination robert lafore

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, arguments

```
int main()
{
void fun(char *);
char str[] = "some text";
fun(str);
return 0;
}

void fun(char* ps){
while(*ps){
cout << *ps++;}
cout << endl;

}
```

So this is one of the examples in a c++ text book by Robert Lafore which illustrates the example of string passed in a function.
While explaining the example it is mentioned that the array address str is passed to the function. **This address is constant, but since it is passed by value here. and a copy of it is created in fun().**

I am not able to understand this statement as it is c style string which is a constant pointer which behaves similar to the array. The name itself should be the address and and we pass address to the function.
My questions are:
How it is being passed by value if the name itself is address?
Why it is the copy being created when we are passing the pointer argument to the fun()?

I got really confused here.
I might be wrong even in my basics, so an explanation would be great here.

Comment: There is no copy of the string. Only the copy of the pointer that points to it. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: The string itself is located at one specific set of memory addresses (with a '\0' at the end).  Then a copy of the pointer is made to pass that location to fun, not the whole string. Same for "C" style arrays, but they don't have a trailing zero and you must pass a pointer to the start and a size (or use std::array, or std::vector)

)for C++ I would recommend using std::string and learn about passing by reference)

Comment: The "constant-ness "of `str` means that doing `++str` is not possible. However, the parameter `ps` is just a pointer, and not an array, so it can be incremented. This is low level C-stuff that is less important in C++.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, every parameter (variable) of function is stored <strike>on the stack (special memory dedicated to local variables)</strike> somewhere and acts as new variable.

So your function:

```
void fun(char* ps)
{
 ...
}
```

has variable 'ps' of type 'pointer to char' which exists within the scope of 'fun' function and nowhere else.

So when you use it from other function (such as your main), then you'll have two variables containg pointer to the "some text" string. Namely 'str' inside main and 'ps' inside 'fun' function. The 'ps' is that copy mentioned in the book.

Also you have to distinguish between term 'address' and 'variable'. Address is WHAT is stored and variable is WHERE it is stored.

So for example, this code:

```
char my_character = 'x';

char *a = &my_character;
char *b = &my_character;
char *c = &my_character;
```

are three DIFFERENT variables (the one having type char*) but they ALL contain same value - address of my_character variable.

Comment: OT: _"every parameter (variable) of function is stored on the stack"_ — Technically, this is generally incorrect. Arguments are passed according to the _calling conventions_, which are part of a given ABI. Pointer arguments are typically passed by a register. Note that C++ itself even does not know the stack concept.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a look at what is happening in each of the statements in your program.

##### Statement 1

Here we consider the statement `void fun(char *);`.

This statement is a **declaration** for a function named `fun` that has one **parameter** of type `char*` and return type of `void`. This means that this function takes a *pointer to char*(`char*`) as **argument by value** and returns nothing(`void`).

##### Statement 2

Here we consider the statement `char str[] = "some text";`

This statement **defines** an array of `char` named `str`. That is, the type of `str` is `char [10]`.

##### Statement 3

Here we consider the statement `fun(str);`

This statement **calls** the function named `fun` by passing `str` as an argument. There are 2 important things to note here:

1. Since the argument is passed **by value**, `str` **decays** to a *pointer to `char`* due to **type decay**. This means, `char [10]` decays to `char *`. Remember from statement 1 that the function `fun` expects a `char*` as argument and this is exactly what we are supplying/providing it. In particular, we are providing it a *pointer to the first character of the array* which is nothing but `char*`.
2. By value means the argument is **copied**. But note that in our case the argument is nothing but a `char*`(from point 1 above due to decay).This is why it is written that:

> but since it is passed by value here. and a copy of it is created in fun().